# how to console log with Javascript Splade shared data

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Splade with laravel and I want to console log the shared value as per the URL shared below for the Splade documentation.

https://splade.dev/docs/shared-data

```
Splade::share('adminLastSeenAt', Admin::value('last_seen_at')->toIso8601String());

<x-splade-state>
    <p>Admin last seen at: <span v-text="state.shared.adminLastSeenAt" /></p>
</x-splade-state>
```

I want to console log (**adminLastSeenAt**)

I'm trying to console log the value from the splade shared data from backend laravel.